# Sending uploaded image to jsp via ajax

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

First sorry if my question is basic, but really I have no idea how to handle it:)

I have an upload button that when I click on it I can upload image to the server my html code is as follow:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>File Uploading Form</title>
</head>
 <body>
<h3>File Upload:</h3>
 Select a file to upload: <br />
 <form action="fileupload.jsp" method="post"
                    enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="file" name="file" size="50" />
 <br />
 <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
  </form>
  </body>
  </html>
```

And a jsp file that shows the result is as follow:

```
     <%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*, javax.servlet.*" %>
     <%@ page import="javax.servlet.http.*" %>
     <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.*" %>
      <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.*" %>
      <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.fileupload.servlet.*" %>
       <%@ page import="org.apache.commons.io.output.*" %>
  <html>
   <head>
      <title>File Uploading Form</title>
       </head>
      <body>

<%
String str="service_twitter_on2.png";
File file ;
String fileName="";
 int maxFileSize = 5000 * 1024;
    int maxMemSize = 5000 * 1024;
       ServletContext context = pageContext.getServletContext();
     String filePath = context.getInitParameter("file-upload");
    /* filePath="C:\\Users\\Hamed\\Desktop\\temp\\"; */
    filePath="E://ws//rrr//WebContent//images//";
       // Verify the content type
        String contentType = request.getContentType();
     if ((contentType.indexOf("multipart/form-data") >= 0)) {

  DiskFileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();
  // maximum size that will be stored in memory
  factory.setSizeThreshold(maxMemSize);
  // Location to save data that is larger than maxMemSize.
  factory.setRepository(new File("c:\\temp"));

  // Create a new file upload handler
  ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);
  // maximum file size to be uploaded.
  upload.setSizeMax( maxFileSize );
  try{ 
     // Parse the request to get file items.
     List fileItems = upload.parseRequest(request);

     // Process the uploaded file items
     Iterator i = fileItems.iterator();

     out.println("<html>");
     out.println("<head>");
     out.println("<title>JSP File upload</title>");  
     out.println("</head>");
     out.println("<body>");
     while ( i.hasNext () ) 
     {
        FileItem fi = (FileItem)i.next();
        if ( !fi.isFormField () )   
        {
        // Get the uploaded file parameters
        String fieldName = fi.getFieldName();
        fileName = fi.getName();
        boolean isInMemory = fi.isInMemory();
        long sizeInBytes = fi.getSize();
        // Write the file
        if( fileName.lastIndexOf("\\") >= 0 ){


        file = new File( filePath +  fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"))) ;
        str=fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\"));
        }else{

        file = new File( filePath + 
        fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1)) ;
        str=fileName.substring(fileName.lastIndexOf("\\")+1);
        }

        fi.write( file ) ;
        /* out.println("Uploaded Filename: " + filePath + fileName + "<br>"); */
        out.println("Uploaded Filename: " + filePath + fileName + "<br><br>");

        }
     }
     out.println("</body>");
     out.println("</html>");
  }catch(Exception ex) {
     System.out.println(ex);
  }
    }else{
        out.println("<html>");
      out.println("<head>");
       out.println("<title>Servlet upload</title>");  
        out.println("</head>");
         out.println("<body>");
           out.println("<p>No file uploaded</p>"); 
        out.println("</body>");
        out.println("</html>");

        }
      %>
     <img src="images/<%=str%>"/>
    </body>

      </html>
```

and it works but I want to send the image that user uploads through ajax (and recieve it in a servlet) rather than using form.  I searched lot but I could not find any good example!

Can anyone help me?

Comment: http://www.programdiary.in/2013/02/fileuploading.html check out this link are you trying to upload file without refreshing the page

Comment: Don't attempt Ajax for fileuploads until you learn to indent code and use servlets for saving things on the server rather than JSP.

Comment: @user3127499 thanks but that code is not working

Comment: @developerwjk You are right I have to separate servlet and jsp and also being careful about my indentation but the above code was just a quick example to show what I did:)

Comment: For more explanation,I know how to use ajax and doget and dopost when the parameter is string type but here parameter is an image so I do not know how to send image as a parameter

Comment: This is really a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery

Comment: How to handle the upload serverside is explained here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-to-server-using-jsp-servlet

Comment: @developerwjk thanks a lot your help made a lot of improvement for me but in the middle of testing I got to strange error so I posted it as a new question can you please take a look:                                        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690860/when-i-use-method-post-and-enctype-multipart-form-data-still-i-get-error